# ReferenceError: insertRecord is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, referenceerror

I have this html code that's supposed to retrieve a local json file and have it parse and stringify to the local storage. I wanted to test the code, but when I fill out the form and run it, it says ReferenceError: insertRecord is not defined in Firefox console.

Any help would be very much appreciated.
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Register</title>
<link href="css/navigation.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/body.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="store.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i;
var user;
var txt;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "studio.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: getUser,
    error: function() {alert("retrieval error"); }
});
});

function getUser(data) {
if (localStorage) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('user')) {
        user = JSON.parse(data.User);
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);
    }

    else {
        String item = localStorage.getItem('user');
        user = JSON.parse(item);
    }
}

else
    alert("Local Storage not supported");
}

function insertRecord() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "studio.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: insertUser,
    error: function(){ alert("retrieval error"); }
});

function insertUser() {
    txt = { firstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
            lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
            userName: document.getElementById("userName").value,
            email: document.getElementById("email").value,
            password: document.getElementById("password").value
          };
    localStorage.setItem('user', user + JSON.stringify(txt));
}
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<img src="images/Dance etc logo LARGE.jpg" width="263" height="150" alt="Dance Etc Logo" />
<hr />
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Dance Etc.</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" >
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post" action="" id="register" name="form">
    <label>First Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" /><br />
    <label>Last Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" /><br />
    <label>Username: </label>
    <input type="text" id="userName" /><br />
    <label>Email: </label>
    <input type="text" id="email" /><br />
    <label>Password: </label>
    <input type="password" id="password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Register" onClick="insertRecord()" />
    </form>
</div>

<div data-role="footer">
    <a href="Dance_Program">Contact Us</a>
    <a href="Register">Policy</a>
    <a href="Login">History</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have the following line:

```
String item = localStorage.getItem('user');
```

This isn't valid JavaScript and is therefore throwing a `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`, preventing the rest of your JavaScript code from being evaluated.
However, as you try to attach `insertRecord` inline in the HTML, it tries to run when triggered, but can't invoke code that didn't get evaluated.

You should consider attaching event listeners using [`element.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener).
Additionally, indenting your code may help you debug, too.

```
var i, user, txt;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "studio.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: getUser,
        error: function () {
            alert("retrieval error");
        }
    });
});

function getUser(data) {
    if (localStorage) {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('user')) {
            user = JSON.parse(data.User);
            localStorage.setItem('user', user);
        } else {
            item = localStorage.getItem('user');
            user = JSON.parse(item);
        }
    } else
        alert("Local Storage not supported");
}

function insertRecord() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "studio.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: insertUser,
        error: function () {
            alert("retrieval error");
        }
    });

    function insertUser() {
        txt = {
            firstName: document.getElementById("firstName").value,
            lastName: document.getElementById("lastName").value,
            userName: document.getElementById("userName").value,
            email: document.getElementById("email").value,
            password: document.getElementById("password").value
        };
        localStorage.setItem('user', user + JSON.stringify(txt));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Paul_S. Hello, thanks for the response. I've tried running as item = localStorage.getItem('user') but then it tells me SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character.

Comment: That means `data.User` does not contain valid JSON. Please verify your JSON is valid, e.g. at http://jsonlint.com/